# Service 'org.freedesktop.UDisks2' does not exist

Tags: d-bus, udisks

I am using Debian Sid, with OpenRC init system. I have installed the latest udisks2 (2.8.4), as well as qdbus-qt5. Earlier (an unspecified time before this error popper up), I was able to query `org.freedesktop.UDisks2` interface using `qdbus` command. Now when I run the command I get the following error.

```
$ qdbus org.freedesktop.UDisks2
Service 'org.freedesktop.UDisks2' does not exist.
```

I have ensured that `udisksd` is up and running. This error is coming up after I upgraded my system. However, `udisksctl status` promptly displays

```
MODEL                     REVISION  SERIAL               DEVICE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
WDC WD10SPZX-00Z10T0      01.01A01  WD-WXP1AB8HPJ11      sda     
TSSTcorp DVD+/-RW SU-208GB D100      S16A6YGGA000GC       sr0
```

Also, when I try to access `org.freedesktop.UDisks2` interface from inside a Qt program using `QDBusInterface`, I do not get any errors. Any help in resolving this issue would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe one of the recent changes to qdbus might have resulted in this issue. After a little trial and error, I found out that since UDisks2 is a system bus, we need to use the `--system` switch to access it using qdbus. So the above commands become

```
$ qdbus --system org.freedesktop.UDisks2
```

Which give me the desired output

```
/
/org
/org/freedesktop
/org/freedesktop/UDisks2
/org/freedesktop/UDisks2/drives
....
....
```